# Passing on values from file to object in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file which has stored different movies and its attributes, then I want to create objects called movie. This is my movie class;

public class movie {

```
static Scanner userInputInt = new Scanner(System.in); 
static Scanner userInputString = new Scanner(System.in); 
static Scanner userInputDouble = new Scanner(System.in);

int ID;
String name;
String genre;
int length;
int year;
String director;
int sumOfRatings;
int totalRatings;
double averageRatings;
int totalViews;

public static movie[] readMovies() {
    movie[] tempMovie = new movie[100];
    int line = 0;

    try{
        BufferedReader myFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("moviefile.txt")); 
        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = myFile.readLine()) != null){
            tempMovie [line].ID = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split("\t") [0]); 
            tempMovie [line].name = sCurrentLine.split("\t") [1]; 
            tempMovie [line].genre = sCurrentLine.split("\t") [2]; 
            tempMovie [line].length = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split("\t") [3]); 
            tempMovie [line].year = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split("\t") [4]); 
            tempMovie [line].director = sCurrentLine.split("\t") [5]; 
            tempMovie [line].sumOfRatings = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split("\t") [6]); 
            tempMovie [line].totalRatings = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split("\t") [7]); 
            tempMovie [line].averageRatings = Double.parseDouble(sCurrentLine.split("\t") [8]); 
            tempMovie [line].totalViews = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split("\t") [9]); 
            line++;
        }
        myFile.close(); }

    catch (IOException error){
        System.out.println("File cannot be read."); 
    }
    
    movie[] newMovie = new movie[line];
    System.arraycopy(tempMovie, 0, newMovie, 0, line);
    return newMovie;

}
```

}

When I try to call the objects in another class, I get the following error; "Cannot assign field "ID" because "tempMovie[line]" is null". However, with the while-loop it is not supposed to iterate through more of the tempMovie array than the number of entries there are in the file. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to to is initialize your object inside the array, you just created an array, not the object in the position line:

```
...
while ((sCurrentLine = myFile.readLine()) != null){
    tempMovie[line] = new movie();
    ...
}
....
```

PS: Please review your Java code. You are not following the Java Code Convention.
e.g: Class names must start with UpperCase like Movie, for example.

Furthermore, it is a good practice to break apart IO logic of other tiers. Its better to make the IO operations in a class outside your model class Movie.